# JsonMappingException due to illegal unquoted character when sending large request

Tags: java, json, spring, request

I am currently developing a Spring Boot application that involves parsing JSON requests. I am experiencing an issue when I attempt to send a particularly large request to my server. I've found that the application is replacing the latter part of these large requests with null characters, which is causing a JsonMappingException. Here is the error message I receive:

`Bad Request: JSON parse error: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 0)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 7160] (through reference chain: TblMerchantDTO["cases"]->java.util.HashSet[16]->TblCaseDTO["description"])`
From what I've discovered so far, it appears that this error happens when the request exceeds a certain length, resulting in the trailing characters of the request being replaced with null characters (CTRL-CHAR, code 0). These null characters then cause the JsonMappingException due to being unquoted.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how I might solve this issue? Are there any settings or parameters I can adjust to handle large requests correctly without this null character replacement? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

I want to be able to receive requests with long body(not 100MB large, around 10MB).